# FastReport 4 - проблема с "property FillType does not exist"

Tags: delphi-xe, fastreport

Установил по интернет инструкциям FastReport v4 (восстановление после падения Windows). FastReport заработал, если создавать новый проект.
Но случилось страшное - все проекты созданные **до**, перестали компилироваться.
Стали выдавать критические ошибки (пример):
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным? И как вышел из ситуации, если сталкивался?
Что-то, как я понимаю связано с заполнением заголовка репорта. Они все из проекта открываются нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: hy]

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался! Методично пересохранил все имеющиеся в проекте репорты и всё заработало.
Выходит они были скомпилированны по средствам другой версии FastReport.
Не удаляю вопрос - так как, возможно, будет кому-то полезен при миграции из одной ОС в другую.

Comment: Вы можете сравнить шаблоны "до" и "после" конвертирования (например, diff), чтобы понять в чем дело (заодно, в заголовке шаблона будет указана версия редактора). Сами шаблоны, начиная с версии 5 (кажется), это просто XML файлы с человекочитаемым текстом.